# Encryption in python that the output is one char

Tags: python, udp, aes, encryption-symmetric

I'm looking for symmetric encryption for UDP.
So I have understood that I can use caesar encryption, but it's too weak.
So now I need symmetric encryption in python that encrypts one char and the output of this encryption is one char.
Thanks for helping !

Comment: What you describe (1 byte message -> 1 byte encrypted message) is know as streaming cipher.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are after this:

https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html

Comment: AES is by default a block cipher. Just pointing to the AES documentation is not what I would call a good answer. You should at least point out those modes that allow to work with AES like a streaming cipher (as requested in the question).